# Show admin button for the user with role 'admin'

Tags: yii, yii-components

I created a role 'admin' using RBAC and now I need to show admin button in the main menu if logged in user has such a role. How can I realize that?

Comment: you are using Yii1 or Yii2 .?

Comment: you can refer this link for RBAC : http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/328/simple-rbac/

Comment: I'm using Yii 1.1